# X chromosome "weight"?

Tags: cell-biology, cytogenetics

According to Wikipedia, the [X chromosome](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X_chromosome#Function) has approximately 153 million base pairs, while the [Y chromosome](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Y_chromosome) has only 60 million base pairs. Thus, the difference is roughly 93 million base pairs.

My question is: Could this "extra" 93 million base pairs in virtually every single female cell of the human body slightly contribute to the "extra" relative weight of the female as a whole, in comparison to a male (of course) with a similar amount of cells? Or would this weight be so small that we can consider it negligible?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Theoretically...

`93 million bp/cell x 650 daltons/bp x 10^13 cells/body x 1.66 * 10^-27 kg/dalton = 0.001 kg`

So I would say it's not too much of a difference :P

however this ignores the rest of the chromosomal material: histones

Comment: Not too much of a difference, but it's something! Thanks.

Comment: Girls take note, this is not a valid excuse. Seriously though, this difference is exploited in some (albeit minimally effective)  techniques to sort sperm for gender selection.

Comment: Yep. Believe it or not, X sperm swim slower than Y sperm.

Comment: So, what is the difference in weight between X and Y sperm?

Comment: Very small. Using the same method as above yields an answer of around 0.1 picograms.

Comment: @ bobtheowl2, @ jp89: Could you provide some reference for the sorting procedure?

Comment: Is that difference due to the weight or rather the metabolism of the sperm due to having a different sized genome?

Comment: Hmmm, is it really true that Y sperm swim faster? If that were the case, you would expect that there be more men than women.

Comment: And indeed we do see such an imbalance. There are more male conception to female conception. Estimated 160 male conceptions to 100 female. There are 107 male birth to 100 female birth. But you can see males are losing individuals due to spontaneous abortions. This comes from males have only one X chromosome. A bad copy of a ChrX gene and you die if you are male.